# Autohotkeys cannot recognize Google Chrome Windows. What can I do?

Tags: google-chrome, shortcuts, autohotkey

I am creating a hotkey in autohotkeys, to activate Google Chrome, or move between all Chrome windows.

The HotKey is <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> (h meaning http).

If the user presses <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> it opens a new chrome window

If the user presses <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> twice, it moves between all chrome windows:

**Update:** See the full script in the bottom. Thank  you everyone:

The problem is that AutoHotKeys cannot find the class of chrome, so it's always open new window:

This function always returns false:
`If WinExist ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1`

Please advise.

the script file:

```
#h::
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
If WinExist ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1
{
ifWinActive
WinActivatebottom ,Chrome_WidgetWin_1
else
WinActivate 
return
}
run chrome.exe
```

---

I found the bug.

There is a bug with ifWinExist function in this version of AutoHotkeys, and Google Chrome.
The user can use;

```
WinActivate ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1
```

but cannot use:

```
If WinExist ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1
```

It is always false!

Hope this question&answer help to someone (I cannot write answer, because I have only 1 reputation point)

**Update:**
This is ahk source code, for
<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>n</kbd> Open Notepad or switching between open notepads.

### + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>n</kbd> Open new notepad.

<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> Open cmd.exe or switching between console windows.

### <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> Open new console.

<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>h</kbd> Open Google Chrome or switching between Chrome windows
 + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>h</kbd> Open new browser.

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2


;********command line
#c::
IfWinExist ,cmd.exe
{
ifWinActive
WinActivatebottom ,cmd.exe
else
WinActivate
return
}
#+c::
run cmd.exe
return

;******************Chrome
#h::
IfWinExist ,Chrome
    {
    ifWinActive
        {
        WinActivatebottom ,Chrome
    }
    else
    {
        WinActivate
    }
    return
}

#+h::
run "chrome"
return 
;**************Notepad
#n::
IfWinExist ,Notepad
    {
    ifWinActive
        {
        WinActivatebottom ,Notepad
    }
    else
    {
        WinActivate
    }
    return
}

#+n::
run "notepad"
return
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Please paraphrase.

Comment: This function always return false: IfWinExist ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use the name only (since Google once changed the class name). Here is an expample in AHK_L that I use.

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2

#ifWinActive, Chrome
    NumpadIns::Send, {Click}
    NumpadRight::Send, ^{PgDn} ; Right arrow = activate next Tab
    NumpadLeft::Send, ^{PgUp} ; Left arrow = activate previous tab
#ifWinActive
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Chrome_WidgetWin_0.

If that doesn't work find out what it's real class is by using [WinGet](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinGet.htm)

```
WinGet,activeId,ID,A  <- gives active window ahk_id
WinGetClass, activeClass, ahk_id %activeId%
```

you can also try to search by name

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
WinGetTitle, OutputVar , Chrome <- type the name of the chrome window ( probably contains chrome)
```

You can still refer to this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/106890/how-can-i-use-autohotkey-to-focus-on-an-existing-google-chrome-tab-not-a-conta) if everything else fails.