# In Chrome change tabs using one key only

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a way, using Chrome, to change tabs using just one key? I wish I could use <kbd>F2</kbd> and <kbd>F3</kbd> for past and next tab.

Today I can use <kbd>Ctrl(CMD)+Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl(CMD)+Shift+Tab</kbd> which is a pain!

I walked through a lot of extensions and configurations but none seems to implement this feature.

Any help?

Comment: I don't know about extensions, but perhaps [AutoHotkey](http://superuser.com/questions/106890) can help.

Answer (score 3):

You could try using [Chrome Toolbox](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-toolbox-by-google/fjccknnhdnkbanjilpjddjhmkghmachn?hl=en-US&utm_source=chrome-ntp-launcher) which has the option to switch tabs using mouse scroll:
[image: pic]

Thats definitely quicker than a key press.

P.S I would have written this as a comment but unfortunately i don't have such privileges yet. A couple of vote ups sure would be handy.

Comment: Actually that's a good answer, it's clear and helpful.

Answer (score 1):

use Ctrl(CMD)+Page Up or Ctrl(CMD)+Page Down.
it allows you to use your right hand (with thumb rest on Ctrl, while middle finger chooses the Page keys), and is at least a second option depending on where you are typing before and after the execution.
it also translates to the same type of function in spreadsheet programs like excel and google spreadsheet (for GSS: rest your thumb on Ctrl+Shift.)

Answer (score 0):

trick is to bring your 2 tabs **in new chrome Window** and then use the ctrl + tab to switch between them

1. select both tabs (using Ctrl or drag them one by one)
2. drag & detach them to **new Window**
3. now use the same **Ctrl + Tab** in this new isolated window which only goes to next tab

because there are only 2 tabs in this new window you end up switching between them with the same key combinations